# Why some disk work is hidden Windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, cpu-usage

I have question about Windows OS. You must have heard the issue of high disk usage, or high cpu usage in Windows computers(7, 8 and 10). My question is, why the process that uses that much disk is hidden. This usage can be caused by windows processes or sometimes virus. I would like to know why I can't see which process uses disk when my disk usage is %100. It is more annoying that the most disk using process in the task manager uses 0.1 mb/s and I still have %100 disk usage. My question is not "how to resolve high disk usage". I am asking why windows hiding some processes that we cannot see which program uses that %100 disk which almost freezes the computer. A virus may hide itself but if Windows did show us every program that uses disk, we could be more certain about virus attack because they hide processes.

Comment: If the disk itself (or the disk controller) is having problems then it can cause the disk to be 100% busy for spurts, or even constantly. This is reported back to Windows via the drivers, yet it's not a Windows process that's causing it to be busy.  Please edit your question and add details explaining the way(s) in which you tried to find out what's keeping the disk busy, and what diagnostics you've run on the disk, and what those results were.

Answer (score 2):

The usage is not hidden if you run Resource Monitor by clicking on "open Resource Monitor" in the Disk View under Performance in Task Manager.

[image]

If you select a process you see which files the process accesses:

[image]

If the disk shows as 100& busy but no process usage, the controller reports that the disk is busy doing IO operations. If this happens your disk is the bottleneck and you should replace it with a SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that "windows" is hiding anything - You can check what's exactly consuming your disk performance in "windows performance monitor"

1. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249(v=ws.11).aspx
2. http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-use-resource-monitor-windows-7

Also regarding high disk usage, I had this problem on various hardware/windows combinations, sometimes I've disabled super fetch in registry, but now days I just leave computer turned on for night after Windows installations - and problem goes away itself. I believe this initial high disk usage is somehow connected with windows search engine, building search cache etc. I always had this problem only after installing windows. It never happen to me after using computer for few months.

Comment: Performance monitor didnt provide the information when the usage was 100 percent. It goes after waiting sometime thats not the problem. But if superfetch is consuming disk power, I would like to see it in task manager or performance monitor. And I'd like to see it using 100 mb/s.

Comment: various answers to this problem are related to system configuration/drivers/disk caching/etc - check Your system for proper and updated configuration